# Trent Richardson TimePicker to display date as well as time

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

Im using Trent Richardson TimePicker to create a timepicker but i need to display date as well in the control. 
Is there any way to add date or set date format only for timepicker. 
**I know it is possible by using DateTimePicker, but i don't want to use that**
Code: 
Input Field:

```
<input class="fromtime hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field From must be a date." data-val-required="The From field is required." id="item_From" name="item.From" type="text" value="7/23/2014 12:00:00 AM">
```

Jquery Code:

```
 $(".fromtime").timepicker({
                timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss tt",
                onSelect: function (selectedTime) {
                    var minHour = selectedTime.split(':')[0];                        
                    $('#Event_To_Date').datepicker('option', 'hourMin', minHour);                        
                }
            });
```

I tried using onSelect function but by the time onSelect function is fired the value in the textbox is changed.

Comment: Then you should use `$(".fromtime").datetimepicker();`. Refer these examples http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: i dnt want to use datetimepicker i want only the timepicker but i need the date part also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".fromtime").datetimepicker({
                 dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                timeFormat: "hh:mm TT",
                controlType: 'select',
                oneLine: true,
            });
```